# what's the django's proper field for static files which reside in server?

Tags: django, static, field

On my site, there will be detailed-product page and product description text(*.html files), and images will be edited by staff.(and shared, uploaded by git)

I like to manage these html files and image files in a specific directory with a structure.

For example.

```
ROOT/category_1
               /product1/description.html 
                        /small_icon.png
               /product2/
```

Currently my `Product class` has CharField for each components such as `description.html`.

Wonder if there are better way of organizing these static data?

Comment: http://scottbarnham.com/blog/2008/08/25/dynamic-upload-paths-in-django/

Comment: Are y ou gonna edit those contents through your app right on the server, or will you accept data edited by the clients for upload?

Comment: Staffs will edit them on their local computers, and will upload using `git`.